# Problema al intentar detectar colisiones

Tags: unity, unity2d

Soy nuevo en Unity, así que perdón si pregunto una cosa muy obvia. Estoy intentando hacer un "juego" 2D en el que unos círculos se van moviendo por la pantalla y que cuando colisionen, un contador aumente. Tengo un prefab para añadir círculos al que he añadido un componente Circle Collider 2D con la casilla Is Trigger marcada y un script asociado con el siguiente código:

```
public class ColisionesBolas : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int contador;
        
    void Start()
    {
        contador = 0;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        contador++;
        Debug.Log(contador);
    }
}
```

Comment: Todo bien, pero ¿cuál es tu pregunta o el fallo?

Comment: Buff, perdón... Pues que no detecta la colisión

Comment: Ya probaste añadirles un rigidbody?

Comment: No, solo tienen un collider

Comment: Lo he solucionado añadiendo un rigidbody, pero entonces no entiendo cual es la función de los coliders.

Comment: El rigidbody permite que un objeto tenga físicas mientras que el collider le indica la forma usada para detectar las colisiones

Comment: @Mateo añade tus comentarios como respuesta. Pueden servir de ayuda a otro usuario en el futuro.

Comment: Ok. Simplemente no lo hice porque no pensé que con solo eso bastara para arreglar el problema.